# Best Practices for TFS and MVC projects - deploying changes only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, tfs, incremental-build

I have several websites that I manage for a company and they want me to transition to TFS.  As part of their policy, I can only deploy files that have changed since the last deployment.  I.e.  if a view has changed then it gets deployed, if it has not changed then it not part of the deployment package.  They use automated tools for the deployments.

Currently I use a custom tool I wrote that hooks into my local source provider (Vault Pro) and finds all the changes from a given date and copies those files to a zip file.

How can I accomplish something similar with Team Foundation Server?

Answer (score 0):

TFS provides you with an [`SDK`](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk) that you could use to query it from code. Here's the documentation of the [`client API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).